# Source for Tehillim 19:9 after tzitzit?

Tags: tzitzis, tehilim-psalms

I remember in a siddur I used in Israel, after the Yehi Ratzon right after donning Tzitzit in the morning, it had the words from the [second half of Tehillim 19:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.19.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), starting with "Mitzvat HaShem..." until the end of the pasuk, those 5 words. (the Artscroll ones I currently use do not have it).

Does anyone else say this half of a pasuk after tzitzit, or know where the custom may have came from?