# Can you say HaShem's name if you are only saying a partial pasuk?

Tags: tzitzis, divine-names

In a question I recently asked [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117921/source-for-tehillim-199-after-tzitzit), I was asking about a practice I read (but cannot remember) where the siddur had half of Tehillim 19:9 after putting on tzitzit. It got me thinking: is one allowed say the Name of HaShem if they are only saying part of a pasuk, rather than the whole pasuk?

Comment: Why would the amount of pasuk be relevant?

Comment: Because it seems that a full pasuk might not be an issue: https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Not_Saying_Hashem%27s_Name_in_Vain

Comment: Are you allowed to say part of a pasuk at all, irrespective of whether it contains G-d's Name?

Comment: Good point; but I distinctly remember this siddur having it right after the Yehi Ratzon.

Comment: We say partial pesukim containing Hashem's name every time we say Kedusha (קדוש קדוש קדוש and ברוך כבוד - with קק"ק the chazan at least says the first part of the posuk, but with ב"כ he doesn't). Why should this be any different?

Comment: @meir R H Schachter theorizes that the fact that it’s only a partial pasuk is what makes it a davar shebikedusha and therefore can only be said with a minyan

Comment: @JoelK What about other partial pesukim that we say in davening, like ויהי ערב ויהי בקר יום הששי in Kiddush, or יום אשר עמדת לפני ה"א בחורב in Sheish Zechiros? Surely those aren't considered devarim shebikedusha.

Comment: @Meir Surely those also aren't considered part of davening, and indeed not everyone says those.

Comment: @DoubleAA Fine, then, 'טוב להודות לה in Shabbos morning davening. Better? (Also, we say קק"ק and ב"כ in the berachos before Shema, and the generally accepted halachah is that you don't need a minyan for those.)

Comment: @Meir Better, but indeed according to some those wouldn't be said without a minyan

Comment: @DoubleAA What halachic authority says not to say לא-ל אשר שבת (or those particular words in it) without a minyan?

Comment: @Meir at least r saadya gaon (and the sefer haittim prohibits saying it always)

Comment: @meir R Schachter’s definition of davar shebikedushah is praising Hashem not in the context of a beracha or a full pasuk. I don’t think ואנחנו לא נדע fits into that category (it’s not praise)

Comment: @JoelK Thanks for the clarification. I'm not so sure about that - כי עליך עינינו is a form of praise, no? - but anyway, then we're back to 'טוב להודות לה (leaving aside the side discussion about R' Saadya Gaon's and Sefer HaIttim's positions on it).

Comment: @meir I’m not sure about טוב להודות. We’re not directly praising there either, just describing how Shabbat praises Hashem (similar to those who permit an individual to say the kedusha in birchot keriat shema because it’s סיפור דברים בעלמא)

Comment: @JoelK Good point; I didn't consider that. Thanks. There are indeed nuschaos where there are other partial pesukim that seem to fit those criteria but don't have to be recited betzibbur (ויברכו שם כבודך in Vayevarech David, כי אתה ה' מחסי in Krias Shema She'al Hamittah), but I guess R' Schachter is talking about standard Nusach Ashkenaz, which doesn't have those. I'll have to think whether there are any other examples to bring up.